# How can I request password when Usb hardware is plugged in?

Tags: usb, password

at the moment I use Xubuntu 11.10, my question is:
How can I request password when Usb hardware is plugged in?

Example:

I plug usb mass storage: now xubuntu open a window and show me files and folders of a usb mass storage. I want that when I plug usb mass storage (or any other usb hardware) ask a "root/sudo" password and after show files and folder or make other operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### For Ubuntu 11.10

1. Create a .pkla file with the following command.

   ```
   gksu gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/mount-usb.pkla
   ```
2. Paste the following text into the file's contents, and save the file.

   ```
   [Mounting, checking, etc. of external drives]
   Identity=unix-group:admin
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount;org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-check;org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-unmount-others;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-eject;org.freedesktop.udisks.drive-detach;org.freedesktop.udisks.change;org.freedesktop.udisks.luks-unlock
   ResultActive=auth_admin_keep
   ```
3. Logout, and login again.

[Source (Ubuntu Forums)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9877279&postcount=8) I've tested it with two USB drives (one a flash drive, the other an external HDD), and things seem to work perfectly!

Comment: It's works Thanks!!!
Now I have the road to find way to ask authentication for keyboard and mouse connections! Thanks again